# Ubuntu 20.04 battery settings

Tags: 20.04, battery

I have Ubuntu 20.04 on my system AsusX55C and Ubuntu does not display anything when the battery is low of my laptop. So how can I enable that Ubuntu reminds me to charge the laptop when the battery reaches at 40%.Thankyou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by editing `/etc/UPower/UPower.conf`. Open the file as root and edit the `PercentageLow`, `PercentageCritical` and `PercentageAction` values to something you prefer.

Once the settings are what you want, restart the power manager with `sudo systemctl restart upower`.

Hope this helps

Comment: It worked. @Matigo